# How can I convert a list of space separated files to comma separated files, in nmake?

Tags: nmake

Let's say I have a makefile (using nmake) with a SOURCES macro like this:

```
SOURCES = C:\folder\file1.cpp C:\folder\file2.cpp C:\folder\file3.cpp
```

I have a tool that needs to input these files as items in a comma separated list, like this:

```
C:\folder\file1.cpp,C:\folder\file2.cpp,C:\folder\file3.cpp
```

Is there a way, in nmake, to convert SOURCES into a comma separated list?

**Edit:**

Will this work (note the space after the colon)?

```
COMMALIST=$(SOURCES: =,)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my suggested approach can work. The sole caveat is that you need careful spacing for the inputs. For instance, using the question's SOURCES example, COMMALIST would be:

```
,C:\folder\file1.cpp,C:\folder\file2.cpp,C:\folder\file3.cpp
```

By removing the leading space, I get the output I desire.

Comment: Actually you get the desired output even with the leading space. It seems that any trailing space is ignored by NMAKE in this case.